# Passing values from file input to function (on loop) only performs last iteration

Tags: c, file, file-io, hash, linked-list

I have a hash table data structure where I keep a linked list of nodes with names and phone numbers. I've implemented an insert function that hashes the last name and inserts the node accordingly. Input was done manually via the console, and works completely as intended.

I am now in the process of implementing a function that will read this information from a file and call the insert function repeatedly (for each listing). Information in the file is formatted like this:

> Test User 1234567890
>   Test User 1234567890
>   Test User 1234567890

It appears to work properly until I attempt to retrieve the values from my hash table, and I can only retrieve the last value added to the table (from the file, manual inputs work fine). I've followed each input all the way to the point where they are added to the linked list, and they still contain the correct values. I've also checked the hash function to make sure it is not placing them in the incorrect index, but the generated index is the same between the file and manual input.

Here is my file input code:

```
#define DEF_SIZE 50    

char* lastName = malloc(DEF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
char* firstName = malloc(DEF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
char* phoneNumber = malloc(DEF_SIZE * sizeof(char));

printf("\nAttempting to load phonebook from file...\n\n");
f = fopen("phone.txt", "r");

if (f == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    getchar();
    exit(1);
}

int counter = 0;
while (fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", lastName, firstName, phoneNumber) != EOF){
    insert(lastName, firstName, phoneNumber, hashTable);
    counter++;
}
printf("Successfully inserted %d items from the file.");
```

And my insert function:

```
int insert(char *lastName, char *firstName, char *phoneNumber, node *hashTable[]){

    //holder for linked list index
    int hashResult;

    //get key from last name
    hashResult = hashFunction(lastName);
    //create node for adding listing
    node *addNode = malloc(sizeof *addNode);

    //check if malloc is successful
    if (addNode == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    //allocate space for names + number
    addNode->lastName = malloc(strlen(lastName) + 1);
    addNode->firstName = malloc(strlen(firstName) + 1);
    addNode->phoneNumber = malloc(strlen(phoneNumber) + 1);

    //add data to node
    addNode->lastName = lastName;
    addNode->firstName = firstName;
    addNode->phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    //if empty linked list, create first item
    if (hashTable[hashResult] == NULL){
        start p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        p->next = NULL;
    }

    //point new node's pointer to previous node
    addNode->next = hashTable[hashResult];

    //add node to hash table
    hashTable[hashResult] = addNode;

    //return successful
    return 1;
}
```

If anyone knows anything regarding this issue, or how to approach looking for the cause I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: The "add data to node" section in insert is overwriting your newly malloc'd pointers with the passed in pointers. Every new node will point to the same names. Don't you mean the copy the names from the passed in pointers to the newly malloc'd buffers?

Comment: You never make copies of the strings, you just copy references to the same 3 blocks of memory, overwriting them on each `fscanf` call

Comment: @francis why not just use `strcpy`?

Comment: @francis sprintf worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @francis `strcpy(addNode->lastName, lastName);` or `memcpy(addNode->lastName, lastName, strlen(lastName)+1);`